# does android support messaging notification icon bubble (Badge) like iOS

Tags: android

Does Android have feature similar to iOS where it display red Badge bubble icon when there a new notification. I checked Google messaging docs at [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) and there is nothing mentioned about this, however, I recall i saw it in some Android apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Android have feature similar to iOS where it display red Badge bubble icon when there a new notification.

A `Notification` can have a `number`, though when and where that gets displayed on the `Notification` UI is Android version-dependent.

If you mean that the icon in the home screen's launcher should have a badge, no, that is not supported.

Comment: Thank You ... Yes, I meant home screen's launcher have a badge.

Comment: @user836026: You could make a home screen app widget that shows this sort of number, but not directly on a launcher icon.

Comment: @CommonsWare Many devices have launcher badge notification on the SMS and in default email application, is it because they do use their own launcher or customized Android?

Comment: @RaviBhatt: Any launcher is welcome to create their own dedicated shortcuts to apps and put badges on them. That being said, you usually see this with manufacturer launchers, because they control the firmware and therefore know precisely what apps exist that they can set up such badged shortcuts for.