# iOS or Android WhatsApp or Android Gmail like notification badge in all Android phones

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-launcher

I search to implement notification badges (See screenshot below) like WhatsApp or Gmail but I didn't found one standard solution. I look into the Documentation of [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges) but no luck on oppo with Android 10.

I also tried [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) but not working on some phones. Even it will disappear when the notification is dismissed.

I also used [NotificationBadge class from Telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/99f5637dda59bc405734342d3e2448701d63f2d3/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/NotificationBadge.java) but no luck

I came to know that launcher notification badges are not supported. As per @CommonsWare answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252932/5710872)

There must be a solution if WhatsApp is showing notification badges on the same phone, my app should also show a notification count badge. My app shows dot instead of count.

I will be thankful if anyone shares the knowledge, how to implement a notification badge that works consistently like WhatsApp or Just share how WhatsApp and Gmail are doing it.

WhatsApp:[image]   Gmail: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your app will show notification badge as long there is a notification on the Notification tray. If you clear your notification tray, no app will show any notification badge.

Comment: WhatsApp will still show a notification badge even if the user clears the notification tray

Comment: I am using Samsung A30 and have seen some other devices as well. No device showed any notification badge after clearing the notification tray. Could you be more specific about your testing device?